# How to publish/stream roi of rectified images by using image_proc?

Tags: python, opencv, ros, camera-calibration, roi

I am using ROS to control a drone for real-time image processing applications. I have calibrated camera by using [cameracalibrator.py](https://github.com/strawlab/image_pipeline/blob/master/camera_calibration/nodes/cameracalibrator.py) node in Ros. When I use [image_proc](http://wiki.ros.org/image_proc) node to compare raw and rectified images,  I don't get what I want. Although image is rectified, border of the image is getting distorted toward opposite direction as the image below:

[image: left image is raw, right image is rectified]

As a result, rectified image is still useless for me.

Thus, this time, I calibrated my camera using [opencv](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_calib3d/py_calibration/py_calibration.html) so that I can get region of interest (ROI) in the image after undistortion operation. Thus, the rectified image becomes perfect for me. However, I need ROS to do that while streaming rectified image by using image_proc. Is there anyway to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly use the [image_proc/crop_decimate](http://wiki.ros.org/image_proc#image_proc.2BAC8-kinetic.image_proc.2BAC8-crop_decimate) nodelet.
You can configure it using [dynamic_reconfigure](http://wiki.ros.org/dynamic_reconfigure) to set up ROI or interpolation.
However, since these are software operations, interpolation methods should be handled with care (but fastest NN method is standard anyway) since you have a real time application.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. As far as I know, I can use image_proc/crop_decimate for only raw images. But I need rectified images to be cropped and streamed. Did I misunderstand you ?

Comment: Should work if you just remap the subscription topic to the rectified one

Comment: Okay, I will try. However, I dont know how to do since your idea is really general. Is there any tutorial or example that you can recommend ?

Comment: [This](https://answers.ros.org/question/45118/how-to-set-up-image_proccrop_decimate-nodelet-properly/) discussion should give you some hints.